# How to use regex validation in Laravel for uppercase letters, numbers and square brackets and then list as a postcode range?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to convert the user input to a list of postcodes, e.g.

1. If the user types `SW[1-3]` return a list of `SW1`, `SW2`, `SW3`.
2. I also need it to work alphabetically, if the user inputs `LD1[A-D]` return a list of `LD1A`, `LD1B`, `LD1C`, `LD1D`.
3. If the user doesn't use square brackets and just does `LD1` then it should just return `LD1` in the list.

This is what I've tried so far but I can't get the validation to work and I'm not sure I have the best method for creating the list.

```php
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'postcode' => 'required|string|regex:/^[A-Z0-9][\[A-Z\-0-9\]]*$/u',
    ]);

    $postcode_input = $request->postcode;
    $postcode_list = [];

    // check for []'s
    $match = preg_match('/\[[^\]]*\]/', $postcode_input, $matches);
    if($match) {
        $letters = explode("[", $postcode_input)[0] ?? false;
        $numbers = explode("-", str_replace( array('[',']') , ''  , $matches )[0]) ?? false;

        if($letters && $numbers[0] && $numbers[1]) {
            foreach (range($numbers[0], $numbers[1]) as $number) {
                $postcode_list[] = $letters . $number;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $postcode_list[] = $postcode_input;   
    }

    if(count($postcode_list) > 0) {
        foreach($postcode_list as $pc) {
            $pc = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $pc);
            echo $pc . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you resposting the question ? Why did you delete the original one ? (I have, my self, edited your original question to look like this and you repost)

Comment: @matiaslauriti The original question got closed and it gave me the choice to either edit it further or create a new question. Thanks for the edits.

Comment: Why did it get closed ? I am sorry I cannot help you with your question, as I have never done anything similar so I cannot help you, this type of things are out of my reach. I have to really think into it because I have never done anything similar.

Comment: Can you explain how you know it doesn't work. What do you expect to get and what do you actually get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the [range](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) for `[A-Z]` is a single uppercase character, you might use a pattern with capture groups and a branch reset to access the same group number in the alternation.

```
^([A-Z\d]+)\[(?|(\d+)-(\d+)|([A-Z])-([A-Z]))]|([A-Z\d]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([A-Z\d]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times A-Z or a digit
- `\[` Match `[`
- `(?|` [Branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)

  - `(\d+)-(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in **group 2** and **group 3** with `-` in between
  - `|` Or
  - `([A-Z])-([A-Z])` Capture a single char A-Z in group 2 and group 3 with `-` in between
- `)` Close branch reset
- `]` Match `]`
- `|` Or
- `([A-Z\d]+)` Capture **group 4** Match 1+ times A-Z or a digit (in case of only LD1)
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h9U4ok/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/6sKtS)

Example code, using the value from group 2 and group 3 for the range:

```
$pattern = "/^([A-Z\d]+)\[(?|(\d+)-(\d+)|([A-Z])-([A-Z]))]|([A-Z\d]+)$/";
$strings = [
    "SW[1-3]",
    "LD1[A-D]",
    "LD1"
];

foreach ($strings as $s) {
    if (preg_match($pattern, $s, $match)) {
        if (array_key_exists(4, $match)) {
            echo $match[4] . PHP_EOL;
            continue;
        }
        foreach (range($match[2], $match[3]) as $m) {
            echo $match[1] . $m . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
SW1
SW2
SW3
LD1A
LD1B
LD1C
LD1D
LD1
```